# rtmp трансляция на сайт какую ссылку вставлять в src

Tags: rtmp

Настроил nginx на ubuntu 18 (сервер), настроил получение через rtmp, через obs сервер получает поток. Всё ок.
Но как его вывести на сайт. Какой src использовать в каком формате перекодировать (флеш уже не мувитон) и нужно ли вообще?
Начинаю мне кажется изобретать велосипед, поэтому прошу по возможности от вас простое объяснение. Использовать ли ffmpeg или работать с ffplay? И что вообще делать используя бесплатные решения?

Comment: «в каком формате» — HLS, MPEG-DASH

Comment: hls - application/x-mpegURL

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Так же можно создать url: ffmpeg -re -i  rtmp://домен.ru/live/test -c copy -f hls http://домен.ru/mystream.m3u8

Comment: ещё больше запутали )))